# Set SPN To SQL With NT AUthority

Tags: sql, windows-server-2019, spn

I am trying to add SPN entries for my SQL server but SQL server is running under an NT Authority account like SYSTEM or LOCAL SERVICE.

When I put in the setspn code it says it can't find the user. Is this possible to do? Trying to run the following:

```
setspn -L MSSQLSvc/SQLSERVER1 "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help from ACE but the parameters were a bit wrong. For a local service account on a server use the following:

```
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/server.domain.network:1433 domain\ServerName$
```

Answer (score 3):

The NT authority accounts are local computer accounts, and setspn is for domain account.
So you need to the spn for the computer account:

```
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/myserver.mydomain.local:1433 myserver.mydomain.local
```

Comment: Tried that but it comes back with "Unable to locate the account SQLSERVER1"

Comment: Is your sql server joined to an active directory domain?